# How do I pass multiple arguments into a javascript callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

Javascript code:

```
function doSomething(v1,v2){ //blah; }

function SomeClass(callbackFunction,callbackFuncParameters(*Array*))={
   this.callback = callbackFunction;
   this.method = function(){
       this.callback(parameters[0],parameters[1])  // *.*
   }
}

var obj = new SomeClass( doSomething, Array('v1text','v2text') );
```

The problem is if I change function doSomething to

```
function doSomething(v1,v2,v3){ //blah; }
```

I have to change the corresponding line (marked as `//*.*`) in `SomeClass` to

```
this.callback(parameters[0],parameters[1],parameters[2]);
```

What can be done to avoid the `(*.*)` line to be changed no matter how the number of 'doSomething' function's parameters is changed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably want to use the [apply method](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/apply.html)

```
this.callback.apply(this, parameters);
```

The first parameter to apply indicates the value of "this" within the callback and can be set to any value.

Comment: Im a little confused on how to use this functionality. What I want to do is pass a function to a callback like this - myfunction(function(myele) { //use myele }). So I am passing an anon callback function here with the myele parameter being passed to it. How would I do this with your code above?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/osyzc1d4/3/

Answer (score 2):

Another way now available is to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
this.callback(...callbackFuncParameters)
```

Here it is again with the full example from the OP:

```
function doSomething(v1,v2) {
    console.log('doing', {v1, v2});
}

function SomeClass(callbackFunction, callbackFuncParameters) {
   this.callback = callbackFunction;
   this.method = function(){
       this.callback(...callbackFuncParameters); // spread!
   }
}

var obj = new SomeClass( doSomething, Array('v1text','v2text') );
obj.method()
// output: doing {v1: "v1text", v2: "v2text"}
```