# How to pass additional arguments to callback functions in javascript when using .execute()?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, google-analytics, arguments

I'm working with javascript for Google Analytics API but I'm no more than a novice in JS. I have C++ and Java knowledge and I can get along with logical thinking but some things puzzle me. In GA API I get to make a function call like this:

```
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({'ids':'<tableID>',
    'start-date':'<startDate>',
    'end-date':'<endDate>',
    'metrics':'<metrics>',
    'filters':'<filters>',
    'samplingLevel':'HIGHER_PRECISION',}).execute(putToVar);
```

`putToVar()` is a user defined function defined like so:

```
function putToVar(results)
{
    //do processing with the results
}
```

It is my understanding that the `.execute()` method is used to invoke a callback function for the asynchronous call `gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get()`. So I assume what `function1().execute(function2)` does is call `function2` with the return value from `function1` as argument? Is this correct?

I'm in a situation where I need to apply several distinct filters and store them in an array to retrieve as and when required, irrespective of whether the API call returned a results object (it is an async call, so I don't know when the response comes, it is only visible to the callback function).

I would like to pass to the callback function the dimensions of the array in which to store the returned objects so that I can retrieve them on demand later, without worrying about the order in which the responses get processed. I say this because, initially I tried a `for` loop and the order in which I got the response to my API calls were not the same as the order in which I placed API calls for my queries, so there were mismatches.

Since the reference uses this method to invoke the callback function, I would like to know how to pass additional arguments to a callback function like this when using `.execute()` method, when I get to write `putToVar()` function something like this:

```
function putToVar(results,arrayDim)
{
    //Process Results
    //Store in Array[arrayDim] the required value
}
```

I hope I have made myself clear.
I have read the following posts

- [How do I pass multiple arguments into a javascript callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494779/how-do-i-pass-multiple-arguments-into-a-javascript-callback-function)
- [passing arguments to callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615285/passing-arguments-to-callback)
- [How to explain callbacks in plain english? How are they different from calling one function from another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596276/how-to-explain-callbacks-in-plain-english-how-are-they-different-from-calling-o)
- [How to pass additional arguments to callbacks and also access default parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525688/how-to-pass-additional-arguments-to-callbacks-and-also-access-default-parameters)

but none of them seem to use the `.execute()` method and I cannot figure out how to use what they have said. Or, if and how my `.execute()` method (type of callback execution) can be modified to help my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a closure would solve your problem:

```
for(var x = 0; x< n x ++){  //Or any other loop
   (function(x){   //Closure. This line does the magic!!
       var arrayDim = something_that_depends_on_x_or_the_loop,
           param2 = some_other_thing_that_depends_on_x;
       gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({'ids':'<tableID>',
         'start-date':'<startDate>',
          ...
       }).execute(function putToVar(results){   //this fn is defined inline to get access to param1, param2
           //The following alerts will use the *correct* variables thanks to the closure
           alert(x);
           alert(arrayDim);
           alert(param2);
       });
   })(x); //This one too
}
```

The closure does the magic. It will allow to each loop cycle to have its own variables (not shared), so the proper ones will be inside `putToVar` when executed.

I hope it's clear, if not, just let me know.

Just test it!

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: where can I read more about closures? Google is just overwhelming, asking if you can be more specific.

Comment: If you can get the book "Javascript, The Good parts", it has good explanation about them

Comment: Here you have a useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Um, I'm yet to test it. Was having breakfast actually. Will do soon. :)